# Uninstal this shower tub valve

Tags: shower, valve, tub

I need to do some work behind the shower tub valve buthadno idea how to remove this one. I only found two screws one the back panel but the panel is still blockedby the handle. I can't find anyway to remove the handle. I didn't find any screws for the handle. And twist g the handle itself won't loose it either. Any input is deeply appreciated.[image: 9]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out from a similar product manual. The little cap on the top can come off. The screw is hidden inside...

Answer (score 0):

And when you go to re-install the back plate it would be wise to apply a thick continuous  bead of clear (or matching colored) silicone caulking to the back edge. Leave a 1/2 inch break at the bottom for drainage. Your tub spout opening underneath the valve needs to be sealed as well. Check the showerhead while you are there.